# Stylize font in MessageBox in phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to stylize the font that is shown in the MessageBox and is there a way to add a hyperlink in MessageBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some Codeplex-things:

- Promts from here: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/documentation
- http://wpassets.codeplex.com/